# Resizable IO array in Haskell

Tags: haskell

`ArrayRef` seems to be the package that offers resizable IO arrays, however....

`ArrayRef` seems to be way out of date (it won't even compile with the new GHC).

Does anyone know the modern way to create a resizable array in GHC/Haskell?  I may eventually resort to something related (like Sequence), but would like to stick with something with constant time read/modification if possible.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe [`Data.Vector.Mutable`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/vector-0.10.12.2/docs/Data-Vector-Mutable.html)s are resizable.

Edit: `vector` is a great package but they seem to have changed the interface while I wasn't looking, so I can't give good suggestions on how to use it.

Edit 2: Good catch Michael, that would explain why it looked unfamiliar.

Comment: I am writing some toy code with it right now.  It definitely has a grow function that works as I would expect, and can handle unboxed bytes....  I think this should work for me.

Comment: A more recent version of the API is available: http://hackage.haskell.org/package/vector-0.10.12.2/docs/Data-Vector-Mutable.html.